# delegate method returns a null value

Tags: c#, .net

For the past two hours I've been trying to experiment with delegates / events - my aim is to inform users with both the previous book name and new book as a new book name is set.

However, in all cases in my Abstract class, NameChanged(args.ExistingName, args.NewNames); returns null. I can't seem to figure out why, I have tried manually passing through two string params yet visual studio throws an error stating that NameChanged contains a null value.

```
internal interface Iinterface
    {
        void AddContact(string name, string number);
        void RemoveContact(string name);
        void RetrieveContacts();
        void RetrieveByName(string name);
        void RetrieveByNumber(string number);
        string Name { get; set; }
```

### }

```
public abstract class Abstract : Iinterface
    {
        public abstract void AddContact(string name, string number);
        public abstract void RemoveContact(string name);
        public abstract void RetrieveContacts();
        public abstract void RetrieveByName(string name);
        public abstract void RetrieveByNumber(string number);

        public string Name{
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                    NameChangedEventArgs args = new NameChangedEventArgs();
                    args.ExistingName = _name;
                    args.NewName = value;
                    NameChanged(args.ExistingName, args.NewName); // this refers to the abstract class? 
                    _name = value;
            }
        }

        public NameChangedEventHandler NameChanged; // I presume here we're taking an instance of the delegate method. 

        protected string _name;
```

### }

```
public class PhoneBook : Abstract
    {
        public PhoneBook()
        {
            _name = "phone book name";
        }

        public override void AddContact(string name, string number)
        {
            contacts.Add(name, number);
        }

        public override void RemoveContact(string name)
        {
            contacts.Remove(name);
        }

        public override void RetrieveContacts()
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in contacts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} Number : {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value); 
            }
        }

        public override void RetrieveByName(string name)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in contacts)
            {
                if(entry.Key == name)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} Number : {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }

        }

        public override void RetrieveByNumber(string number)
        {
           foreach(KeyValuePair<String,string> entry in contacts)
            {
                if (entry.Value == number)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} Number : {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        Dictionary<string, string> contacts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
```

---

```
 public class NameChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string ExistingName { get; set; }
        public string NewName { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
{
    // public delegate void NameChangedEventHandler(object sender, NameChangedEventArgs args);
    public delegate void NameChangedEventHandler(string existingName, string newName);
}
```

---

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PhoneBook book = new PhoneBook();
            setName(book);
            addContact(book);
            retrieveByName(book);
            retrieveByNumber(book);
            book.NameChanged = new NameChangedEventHandler(OnNameChanged); // call OnNameChanged whenever someone invokes this delegate


            Console.ReadLine();
            /* book.retrieveContacts(); */
        }
        private static void setName(PhoneBook book)
        {
            book.Name = "book name";
            Console.WriteLine(book.Name);
        }
        private static void retrieveByNumber(PhoneBook book)
        {
            book.RetrieveByNumber("0323242389");
        }

        private static void retrieveByName(PhoneBook book)
        {
            book.RetrieveByName("james");
        }

        private static void addContact(PhoneBook book)
        {
            book.AddContact("james", "0151289");
            book.AddContact("Bob", "0323242389");
            book.AddContact("Hannah", "34234");
        }


    static void OnNameChanged(string existingName, string newName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Gradebook changing name from {existingName} to {newName}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: it looks like you use `=`, instead of `+=`.  Has to be like: `book.NameChanged += new NameChangedEventHandler(OnNameChanged);`

Answer (score 0):

For registering a delegate or event with a method, the following is the syntax for it:

```
book.NameChanged+= new NameChangedEventHandler(OnNameChanged);
```

and Secondly you should not be invoking it blindly at invoking side.

you should be checking if someone has subscribed to it or any method is assigned to it like:

```
if(NameChanged !=null)
    NameChanged(args.ExistingName, args.NewName);
```

or in c# 6:

```
NameChanged?.Invoke(args.ExistingName, args.NewName);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That creates a TOCTOU error.  With C# 6, you can write `NameChanged?.Invoke(...)` which does the check in a safe manner, in older versions you need to make a local copy of the delegate, then check and invoke the copy.

Comment: unfortunately with this answer a null value is still returned, however I'll take your second comment on board ! :)